# Webpack Error: Cannot find module 'node:process'

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to bundle a Node script so users don't have to run npm install before using it.

`npx webpack` runs fine and without warnings, but `node dist/main.js` gives the following error: `Error: Cannot find module 'node:process'`.

If I edit `dist/main.js` and comment out the line about `node:process`, the bundled script seems to run just fine.

Here's my webpack config:

```js
export default {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    module: true,
    chunkFormat: 'module',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  experiments: {
    topLevelAwait: true,
    outputModule: true
  }
};
```

Comment: was there a resolution to this?